# How to apply v-once to v-bind:class in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In vue, I have

```
<button v-bind:class="['mdc-tab', {'mdc-tab--active' : index===tabs.currentTab}]"></button>
```

however, this binds it to the variables `tabs.currentTab`. However the `mdc` framework already switches tab classes, so I only need the above to render initially. Something like using `v-once`. However `v-once:class` doesn't work. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't very clear but it sounds to me like you should set `tabs.currentTab` to be some relevant initial value

Comment: that variable is already set. However the above code binds it to the variable with vue. So if I update the variable, vue will update the class. However instead I want to render the above classes just once.

Comment: I want it to create the classes, but without the binding, basically how the library "handlebars" would have done it.

Comment: Simple workaround is making a helper var which you set to the other var and then you can still modify it but the helper holds the initial wanted state in it.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that v-once does not expect an expression: [vue directives v-once](https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/rendering-elements-v-directive)

So all you need to do is:

```
<button v-once v-bind:class="['mdc-tab', {'mdc-tab--active' : index===tabs.currentTab}]"></button>
```